# JavaScript Date constructor and UTC

Tags: javascript, date

If I use `new Date('2015-01-01')`, will that give me a point in time equivalent to `2015-01-01T00:00:00Z`?

Comment: You can try that `+new Date('2015-01-01') == +new Date('2015-01-01T00:00:00Z')`

Comment: from docs see [first sentence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support)

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> constructors: ... dateString String value representing a date. The
>   string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method
>   (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

From [documentation on Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> If a time zone is not specified and the string is in an ISO format
>   recognized by ES5, UTC is assumed

However, depending on this behaviour could be risky, as, from the same document:

> note that [ECMAScript ed 6 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format) specifies that date time strings without a time zone are to be treated as local, not UTC

Comment: could also add that "note that ECMAScript ed 6 draft specifies that date time strings without a time zone are to be treated as local, not UTC"

Comment: This is useful, but it does not answer my question re the Date constructor.

Comment: @BenAston Actually, that's exactly what it answers. The first quote, simplified, says "If constructed from String, Date.parse is used", and second one says "If Date.parse is used without time zone - UTC is assumed". Therefore, if you combine two quotes together, you get "If constructed from String without specifying time zone - UTC is assumed".

Comment: @Hacketo Thanks for information, did not know that. I will update my answer with that.